# Comparing two Strings using Java 8 features

Tags: java

I was exploring various efficient ways to compare two strings in Java and I was comparing below two code snippets

**Approach 1 :- Traditional Way**

```
public static boolean stringCheck(String test1, String test2) {    
    if ((test1 == null) || (test2 == null)) {
        return false;
    }
    return test1.compareTo(test2) > 0;
}
```

and to test this code

```
String test1 = null;
String test2 = null;
boolean isTrue1 = stringCheck(test1, test2);
System.out.println("Return of stringCheck is" + isTrue1);
```

***which prints => Return of stringCheck is false***  which is correct

**Approach 2 :- Using Java 8 Features**

```
public static boolean stringCheckWithJava8(String test1, String test2) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(test1)
            .map(s1 -> s1.equals(test2))
            .orElseGet(() -> test2 == null).booleanValue();
}
```

and to test this code

```
String test1 = null;
String test2 = null;
boolean isTrue = stringCheckWithJava8(test1, test2);
```

**which prints => Return of stringCheckWithJava8 is true**
which is logically correct  .

Now my question is How can I modify my code in Approach 2 with Java 8 feature shown above to handle a to return false when both strings are null?

Comment: Why would you wanna complicate a simple string comparison like that?

Comment: I agree But I was exploring a better way using Java 8 features

Comment: Normally null == null.

Comment: It's not better in any way.

Comment: Why not simply `return (test1 == test2) || (test1 != null && test1.equals(test2))`? Your second approach is not readable at all. Btw, your first code snippet erroneously uses `compareTo`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose
Yes I thought of using Objects.equals(test1,test2 ) ; but it returns true when both strings are null

Comment: By the way,  `test1.compareTo(test2) > 0` is a wrong check for equality - use `test1.compareTo(test2)==0` or simply  `test1.equals(test2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return `false` if `test1` is null. There is no need to test if `test2 == null`.

```
public static boolean stringCheckWithJava8(String test1, String test2) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(test1).map(s1 -> s1.equals(test2)).orElseGet(() -> false).booleanValue();
    }
```

Comment: You can simplify that to `Optional.ofNullable(test1).map(s1 -> s1.equals(test2)).orElse(false)`.

Comment: Yes of Course. There are lot of better ways as other suggested. I thought not to modify author's code too much :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8 features is an abstract concept and includes all things introduced by Java 8, why not use BiPredicate?

```
BiPredicate<String, String> checkIfStringsAreEqual = (str1, str2) -> Objects.nonNull(str1) && Objects.nonNull(str2) && str1.equals(str2);
System.out.println(checkIfStringsAreEqual.test(test1, test2));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use Java 8 at all. You can just simplify your existing method like this:

```
public static boolean stringCheck(String test1, String test2) {
    return test1 != null && test2 != null && test1.compareTo(test2) == 0;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
public static boolean stringCheck(String test1, String test2) {
    return test1 != null && test1.equals(test2);
}
```

If you really want to use Java 8 you can use an `Optional` like this:

```
public static boolean stringCheck2(String test1, String test2) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(test1).filter(t -> t.equals(test2)).isPresent();
}
```